# how to substitute a letter and symbol pairing from a dictionary into a text file of a coded message / Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So for an assignment of mine, I'm making this game where I have to make a game that allows the user to cipher a coded message using a dictionary. What I need the program to do is, that when the user types a letter they then have to type a symbol to make a pairing, then I need that pairing to replace into the ten worded list according to the letter.

This is the (Clues) text file:
A#
M*
N%

This is the coded words text file called (Words):

```
#+/084&"      
#3*#%#+  
8%203:  
,1$&  
!-*%  
.#7&33&
#*#71%  
&-&641'2  
#))85
9&330*
```

And Finally this is what they should look like un-coded (Solved):

ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM

This is my code so far:

```
import csv
def Menu():
    print("Welcome to aqa puzzle code, please choose an option below")
    choice = input("""
            1. To look at the clues
            2. Ten word list and pairings
            3. To enter pairings
            4. Delete pairings
            5. Check if code is right
            6. Press 999 to quit """)

    if choice == '1':
        Clues()
    elif choice == '2':
        WordlistAndPairings()
    elif choice == '3':
        EnterPairings()
    elif choice == '4':
        DeletePairings() 
    elif choice == '5':
        Solution()
    elif choice == '6':
        input("") 

def Clues():
    with open('Clues.txt','r') as f:
        f = f.readlines()
        for line in f:
            print(f)
            Menu()

def WordlistAndPairings():
    print("Ten word list with substitutions made")
    file = open("Words.txt","r")
    openfile = file.read()
    print(openfile)
    file.close()
    Menu()


def EnterPairings():
    pairings = {'letters: [A:Z]', 'symbols: [!],[-],[$],[)],[+],["],[\'],[.],'}
    letters = input("Enter letter")
    if letters is in pairings:
        print("You've already paired this wih another symbol")
        EnterPairings()
    elif letters is not in pairings:
        symbols = input("Enter symbol to go with letter symbol")
        pairings [letters] = symbols 
        print (pairings)
        Menu()

def DeletePairings():
    print("")
    print("Removing a pairing")
    rename = input("Enter the letter you want to remove")
    print(pairings)
    del pairings[rename]
    print(pairings)
    Menu()



Menu()
```

For choice number two(2) I don't I need it to refresh it's self due to the changes made. So if the user was to make a pairing of (F'), I need the program to then go back to the Menu and if the user choose's choice (2), I basically need the user's letter substituted for the symbol. Also under that list I want a list of all the substitutions made by the user and if they delete the pairing then that needs to update if they were to come back to the list. I would be grateful to anyone who could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand your question, and I wouldn't want to just do your homework for you, but here's an example of how to write a function that substitutes characters in a string based on pairings in a dictionary:

```py
pairings = {'#':'A',
            '%':'N',
            '*':'M',
        }

def try_substitution(coded_word, pairings):
    # Create an empty list to hold the decoded letters
    decoded_letters = []
    # Loop over each symbol in the word
    for symbol in coded_word:
        # 'try' is a Python keyword for catching 'exceptions',
        # which are errors that can happen in your code.
        try:
            # Look up this symbol in the pairings dictionary
            decoded_letter = pairings[symbol]
        # KeyError is the exception that happens when you try
        # to look up something that doesn't exist in a dictionary.
        except KeyError:
            # We handle this error case by just keeping the original
            # coded symbol.
            decoded_letters.append(symbol)
        # 'else' means no exception was triggered.
        else:
            # So we can add the decoded letter to our list.
            decoded_letters.append(decoded_letter)
    # Now we join all the decoded letters together.
    # this uses '' (empty string) because we don't want
    # anything separating these letters.
    decoded_word = ''.join(decoded_letters)
    # And return our completed word from the function
    return decoded_word
```

The above defines a dictionary that maps symbols to letters based on the "Clues" file and a function that takes two arguments: an encoded word, and a dictionary of replacements.

If you call that function on one of the encoded words:

```
>>> try_substitution('#3*#%#+', pairings)
'A3MANA+'
```

You'll get a partially-decoded version of your word.

A shorter, fancier way to write the function above would be using [Python's generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) but this is a more advanced feature, and less easy to understand if you're just learning to program or just learning Python:

```
def try_substitution(coded_word, pairings):
    return ''.join(pairings.get(symbol, symbol) for symbol in coded_word)
```

I think if you tinker around to understand the first example, and make a few changes to your code, you should be able to get a working program.

Comment: Thanks on this, this isn't homework, I go to this club just to extend my knowledge on python, we've been asked to make up our own game and I'm doing this. I was kinda puzzled on how the whole dictionary, substitution part, but I think I understand now.

Comment: The trick is that in Python, strings are immutable, so you can't really "replace" a character in a string, you have to build a new string with the characters you want. Even "foo".replace('o', 'a') will just return a new string "faa".